# Xcode - open current file in a NEW window (a real challenge !)

Tags: xcode, shortcut

[image]

Say you have File.m showing in the blue area above.

I want File.m to open in a **new separate window**.

How to do this??

Note that - of course - **IF** you have the ProjectNavigator showing and **IF** you can see the filename "File.m", then double-click on the filename and it will open in a new window.

What I want to do is open **ANOTHER** copy of the **"CURRENT"** file (the one **in the primaryEditor**) in a **NEW WINDOW** - without touching the ProjectNavigator.

Any ideas?  Cheers

---

Note that ... (an excellent page here)

http://realmacsoftware.com/blog/xcode-4-s-less-obvious-shortcuts

if you click on whatever file is in the current primaryEditor, then **shift option apple comma** that will indeed open the following "freaky little-known Xcode popup" ...

[image]

you can then, indeed, choose to open a new window. **(So to be clear, that is exactly what I want to do.)**

So, I want to be able to do that in one step.  Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I somehow open several windows. I close them, but I don't remember how I open them. Any ideas - none of the solutions here is working for me. I mean I have 2 windows with all editors and run button.

Comment: The latter only works for me when I hover cursor over file and then: `Shift`+`Option`+`Command`+`Click`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In XCode's Preferences you can change the following:
[image: xcode preferences]

And then right-click within the primary editor and click "Open in Separate Window"

**Edit:**
Instead of right clicking in the primary editor you can simply type <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (comma)

Comment: Just make sure that the desired file is opened only in one tab, or else it will keep on switching between the tabs instead of opening it in a new window.

Answer (score 24):

##### Open the file what you want to open in the NEW window.

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>

##### Open the file what you want to open in the separated window.

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Comment: Should be the chosen answer.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a new automator service that does the following steps in Xcode:

1. Execute the default shortcut for the "Open in..." menu item (Command-O)
   (if this isn't your current "Open in" shortcut, the workflow will not work. If you still want to test it, just changed your default shortcut :) )
2. Go all the way to the left in the weird "Open in" view
3. hit Enter
4. Current file opened in new window

The only thing you need to do is install the service on osx and map a shortcut to it.

Here a download to the service:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/486t2iz17o0l9dh/Open-New-Window.zip

**INSTALL INSTRUCTIONS**

1.Place Service file in folder ~/Library/Services
2. Open "System preferences"
3. > Keyboard
4. > Tab "ShortCuts" > "Service" > "General"
5. > Set your own shortcut for the service 
6. Go to XCode and test the service by using your very own shortcut

Tested on OS X Mavericks, Xcode 5.0.1

Answer (score -1):

In XCode 4 you can have a split window via View -> Show Assistant Editor. Then choose the same file which you have already opened in the Primary editor by the small right arrows on top of Assistant Editor.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

in the ProjectNavigator.  If you see the file name: Double click on the file name. It will open in a **new window**.

Comment: Hey Brian, please read the question.  From the **ProjectNavigator** simply double-click to open a line item in a new window.  But imagine the ProjectNavigator is not even showing.  Whichever file happens to be OPEN in the EDITOR PANE (blue), I want to OPEN in a NEW WINDOW.