In Xcode, how do I move a block of code from one place to another in the same file without cutting and pasting?
I have this code:
`if available {
}
doSomething()
goToSomeWere()`
How to move this block (2 functions) of code into the "if" without cutting and pasting (using the keyboard)? Is there a shortcut for this in XCode?
On Android Studio I use:

move a line up: Alt + Shift + Up Arrow
move a line down: Alt + Shift + down Arrow


It's
⌘ ⌥ {  to move up
⌘ ⌥ }  to move down
tap anywhere in the line to do one line, or select as many lines as you want.

lol my pleasure!  welcome new user @user26383060 .  I am always asking weird Xcode questions on here, here is an ancient such question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478095/xcode-open-current-file-in-a-new-window-a-real-challenge
